# Регулярное выражение поиска одинаковых букв в функции

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Функция по получению числа того, сколько разных букв повторяются в строке 2 или более раз. Она должна вернуть именно количество этих буквы в строке.
Неважно повторилась буква 2 или 700 раз - я должен получить только один элемент в массив(так как мэтч дает массив), например слово 'aabbccde' - вернет массив из 3 элементов(там буква "а" повторяется, буква "b" повторяется и "с" повторяется), а слово invisibility (хоть там I повторяется 4 раза) - только 1 (т.е. не принципиально сколько раз повторилась буква, нужно вернуть что она повторилась(1),но он мне возвращает в слове invisibility 2 ( так как он видит сначала одну пару I,а потом вторую и возвращает обе). Вот пытаюсь понять, что поменять в регулярке чтобы вернул только 1 элемент в таком случае.

Вот тесты выглядят так

```
(duplicateCount(""), 0);
(duplicateCount("abcde"), 0);
(duplicateCount("aabbcde"), 2);
(duplicateCount("aabBcde"), 2);
(duplicateCount("Indivisibility"), 1)
```

А вот сама функция полностью

```
function duplicateCount(text){
 if (text === "") {
   return 0
 }
  let arr = text.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')
  let count = arr.match(/(\w)\1/g)
  console.log(count)
    if (count === null) {
    return 0
  }
  else {
    return count.length
  }
}
```

пысы. я знаю что задачу можно решить по другому, без регулярок, но я пытаюсь найти именно такой метод

Comment: что то непонятно. "сколько раз повторяется 2 или более букв в строке" повторяются подряд? То есть, в строке aabcdefbcdef только a повторяется? или имеется в виду "встречается более одного раза в любом месте строки"? Тогда Ваш пример с invisibility - некорректен, там нет "повторений подряд" и функция должна вернуть массив из 0 элементов

Comment: Есть строка  допустим 'aabbcd' и если есть буквы, которые повторяются в строке - 2 и более раз , то вернет 1, соответственно эта строка должна вернуть 2, так как есть "аа" и "bb" , а допустим строка "abaaaaaaaa" вернет число 1, так как повторяется только буква а, и неважно сколько раз, главное больше 2. А если строка 'invisibility' то соответсвенно в ней повторяющаяся буква только "i" и повторяется она там 5 раз, но мне надо так напистаь регулярку чтобы в таком слове она возвращала только 1 , а она возвращает мне 2 так как она видит первые 2 буквы I и потом ведет еще вторые 2 буквы I.

Comment: `let count = arr.match(/(\w)(\1)+/g);`.

Comment: После строки "let arr = text.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('')" invisibility выглядить уже так biiiiilnstvy. Есть 2 пары ii.

Comment: let count = arr.match(/(\w)(\1)+/g)

Вот это вариант от Stanislav Volodarskiy помог, спасибо большое!